# I am attempting to get two columns of data separated from a data set

Tags: python, database, pandas, ascii

So I have this data set, and am attempting to seperate out the two columns.

The data itself has about 60,000 lines to it. Here is an example of it;

```
wavelength                intensity
;        [um]                 [W/m**2/um/sr]
   196.078431372549       1.108370393265022E-003
   192.307692307692       1.163428008597600E-003
   188.679245283019       1.223639983609668E-003
   185.185185185185       1.287171166848453E-003
   181.818181818182       1.359603369324039E-003
   178.571428571429       1.441792694647695E-003
```

The code I have written to seperate the two columns is below;

```
df=ascii.read('earth_crescent.dat', data_start=4958, data_end=13300, delimiter=' ')#, names=['wavelength','intensity'])
   # Separating out the wavelength
x = df.loc[ :,['wavelength']].values
# Separating out the intensity
y = df.loc[:,['intensity']].values
```

Which shoots back this error;

```
ValueError: Cannot create TableLoc object with no indices
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: try printing out df and see if the columns are actually separated or not. It's possible that the data is not separated by " " but maybe `\t`.

Comment: Seems like an issue with astopy? https://github.com/astropy/astropy/issues/5973